# jQuery JSON iteration not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting some data from my API that I want to iterate and add to a div, following is the JSON data from my API:

```
{
   "programmes":{
      "outline":"This is a listing of all programmes on sky.",
      "programme":[
         {
            "@id":"1",
            "name":"Programme 1",
            "img-path":"img/default.png",
            "moods":{
               "mood":[
                  "Scared",
                  "Sad"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "@id":"2",
            "name":"Programme 2",
            "img-path":"img/default.png",
            "moods":{
               "mood":[
                  "Happy",
                  "Wide-Awake"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And this is my JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/data",
    data: { get_param: 'value' },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data.programmes.programme, function(index, element){
            console.log(element);
            $("#programmes").append('\
            <div class="col col-md-2">\
                <div class="img-element">\
                        <img src="img/app.jpg" />\
                </div>\
                <div class="text-element">\
                \
                </div>            \
            </div>\
            ');
        });
    }
});
```

And this is what I'm getting in my console when I run my webpage:

[image]

It's printing out line-by-line instead of printing the objects. Anywhere I am going wrong here?

Comment: A good use case for string template literals ( `` ), and which console is this?

Comment: @Andreas Updated answer, I think I wrote the wrong code on the question before.

Comment: Not reproducible: https://jsfiddle.net/vmo0y27t/

Comment: IT IS PRINTING OBJECTS! I dont get your question

Comment: @Jonasw It's printing out objects multiple times in one loop for one call. I only want "Programme 1" and "Programme 2" being outputted once, not multiple times as being shown in the console.

Comment: What logging have you done? Did you try logging before and after the `$.each` to see if the callback is happening more than once? Have you tried logging the entire response instead of looping to see if there are actually duplicates in the data you're receiving? Seems like you'll find the answer with a little more examination.

Comment: Are you sure you are only getting the above data in your json ? and not the repeated one?

Comment: It looks like the function was being invoked from somewhere else multiple times on page load. At first it didn't make sense but I managed to figure it out. Thanks for the help!